# Help with brute force method of producing bifurcation diagrams of discrete-time systems

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I have a homework question concerning a brute force method of creating bifurcation diagrams. This seems really abstract for me and would like a clearer description of how the method works. Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the image edit!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the way these bifurcation diagrams are produced is to slowly step through a range of values for your bifurcation parameter and for each value, choose a bunch of random points and iterate your map on them a large number of times. By doing this, these points should tend toward whatever stable points you have. Throw away the early values of where the point is as these aren't particularly interesting, but plot all the later points against the value of your bifurcation parameter and that way you'll clearly see these stable sets and how they change.

Comment: Okay this makes much more intuitive sense. Can you explain in more detail how they do the second iteration with the n times? I assume they just plot the final values of n?

Comment: Not quite. As I said, you iterated a bunch of times (N) without plotting as these points will tend to just depend on your starting point and aren't interesting but then you iterate an additional bunch of points (n) which are all plotted as these will be the $\omega$ limit sets for your starting point. You don't just plot the last point though because you may have periodic orbits as your $\omega$ limit set.